# Magento send email after 1 week

Tags: php, magento, email, cron

I am building a module which needs to send email 1 week after purchase is done. How to make this if there is no cron enabled in client website?

I was thinking about two solutions:
1.
When user download extension, he needs also to register and write website url. Each week I run maincron.php on my site. This script will check in database for all websites and then

```
foreach($websites as $website){
  file_get_contents($website['url'].'/myModuleController/cron'.)
}
```

2.
I can put in main controller of the module the code which will check if the day of current week is Monday am. If it is, it will check in database if new emails were already sent. If no, send and save timestamp of the last run. For each visit it will go through this code but only first visit on the mentioned day will trigger the send new emails run.

What do you think about that? Which solution is better, is any other way?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the magento scheduler or send by mail, create the scheduler file and that is set on the server that is find under the CRON JOBS section.

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? How to make this if there is no cron enabled in client website? Not all of them have enabled that and not all of them know how to do it. Magento scheduler also needs to have cron enabled. Or am I wrong or missing anything?

Comment: Sir, CRON Jobs available in the CPANEL, there you can set the file according to your time. 
and file send the mail according to your set time.

Comment: This is going to be a module for other clients and not all of them know how to set cron jobs and not all of them have cpanel. Cron is not solution in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Magento allows you to schedule custom tasks in an XML configuration, in a similar manner to the UNIX crontab style. Here is an example from app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/etc/config.xml:

```
<config>
...
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <catalogrule_apply_all>
                <schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>catalogrule/observer::dailyCatalogUpdate</model></run>
            </catalogrule_apply_all>
        </jobs>
...
    </crontab>
...
</config>
```

This example will run Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer::dailyCatalogUpdate method every day at 01:00am (0 1 * * *).

You can extend this functionality in your own custom modules. To utilize this, inside of your module’s config.xml add the following:

```
<config>
...
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <namespace_module>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0,15,30,45 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>module/model::method</model>
                </run>
            </namespace_module>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
...
</config>
```

That will run every 15 minutes on the quarter hour.

To execute all these configured tasks, the cron.php file located in the Magento root will need to be run periodically, for example every 15 minutes. Basically, this script will check if it needs to run any tasks, and if it needs to schedule any future tasks.

NOW you can send the timer according to you...

Comment: This won't work if cron is not enabled! And since not all clients who will use this modul have cron enabled or access to cpanel, this is not a solution for me.